# cURLing gmail account

Tags: curl, gmail

Does anyone know how to format curl so i can access my gmail and check if there's some new mail?

P.S. I'm sorry, I forgot to mention one huge thing - i'm using PHP, not console! :( Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3386/check-your-unread-gmail-from-the-command-line):

```
curl -u username --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | perl -ne 'print "\t" if /<name>/; print "$2\n" if /<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/;'
```

Just tried it out and it worked for me. cURL is awesome.

Update: this uses [Gmail's atom feed for unread messages](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/03/feed-for-unread-gmail-messages.html). Which uses ssl/https and http authentication so no OAuth necessary.

Comment: Good point, and I agree this is a good solution.  I found that I had to do -k to turn off cert verification.  I stand corrected.

Comment: can you get the subject with this? not just the title of the unread email?

Answer (score 3):

You can curl your gmail's rss feed/xml with this function

```
function check_email($username, $password)
{ 
    //url to connect to
    $url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"; 
    // sendRequest 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    //returning retrieved feed
    return $curlData;
}
```

Then you can return your data either by extracting values from the xml..

```
$em = "youremail@gmail.com";
$pw = "yourpassword";
$feed = check_email($em, $pw);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
    echo "<ul>";
        foreach($x->entry as $msg){
            $href = $msg->link->attributes()->href;
            $qmark = strpos($href,"?")+1;
            $qstring = substr($href,$qmark);

            echo "<li><a href=\"step2.php?".$qstring."\">".$msg->title."</a><br />".$msg->summary."</li>";
        }
    echo "</ul>";
```

Or by just viewing the feed, depending on what you want to do with it..

```
$em = "youremail@gmail.com";
$pw = "yourpassword";
$feed = check_email($em, $pw);
echo $feed;
```

Answer (score 0):

I take my previous answer back, the one liner above does work, although you might need to specify -k in order to turn off certificate verification.